# Node Js project with Docker throwing an error of no such file or directory /var/www/package.json

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-volume, docker-run

I'm new to Docker and following some tutorials. I'm trying to run my node js(express) project with docker volume on Windows 10 machine, here is what I have tried

```
docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /$(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

However, this gives an error

```
npm ERR! path /var/www/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-11-25T18_11_06_089Z-debug.log
```

I just don't understand what is the issue here.

**Edit:**
I'm running docker command from a folder

[image]

Comment: What is the output of: `docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /$(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node ls`?

Comment: It's not giving an output though @UkuLoskit